# How to convert an int into a string?

Tags: c++

Friends, I want to know how to convert an int value into a string value.

Comment: `std::string x =std::to_string(func())`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string):

```
int i = 42;
std::string s = std::to_string(i);
```